# How to avoid HTTP request rate limit inside a websocket client Javascript?

Tags: node.js, websocket, axios, rate-limiting

I want to avoid the HTTP request rate limit when listening to websocket server(not more than one request per second), but the below code doesn't work because `await` is non-blocking:

```js
import WebSocket from "ws"
import axios from "axios";

const ws = new WebSocket(`example_url`)

var lastRequestTimestamp = 0

ws.on("message", async function message(data) {
    const interval = Number(new Date().getTime()) - lastRequestTimestamp;
    if (interval <= 1000) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000 - interval));
    }
    //If fulfill the condition from websocket data, do the HTTP request
    if (data.status){
        axios.post(...)
        lastRequestTimestamp = Number((new Date()).getTime())
    }}
)
```

How should I fix the above code?